# Subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are polyhedra (Rourke and Sanderson)

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, geometric-topology

I have started working through Rourke and Sanderson's ``Introduction to Piecewise-Linear Topology" and have come to a snag quite early on. Among the first few examples of polyhedra are the following,

> $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a polyhedron. The subset $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$, defined by $x_{n}\geq 0$, is a polyhedron. Subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are polyhedra.

It may also be worth mentioning that the metric used on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the the sup metric.

The first two of these I was able to work out alright. This last one about subspaces is tricky. In part because I am unfamiliar with the authors' definition of subspace, which is the following:

> ``Linear" always means linear in the affine sense; thus a linear subspace (or just a subspace) $V\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a translated vector subspace, or equivalently: for each finite set $\{a_{i}\}\subset V$ and real numbers $\lambda_{i}$, with $\sum\lambda_{i}=1$ we have $\sum\lambda_{i}a_{i}\in V$.

Polyhedra are defined in the following way:

> Let $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Define their join $AB$ to be the subset $AB=\{\lambda a+\mu b|a\in A< b\in B\}$ where $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, $\lambda,\mu\geq 0$ and $\lambda+\mu=1$. If $A=\emptyset$ we define $AB=B$. If $A=\{a\}$ is a singleton we denote the join $\{a\}B$ by $aB$. We say that $aB$ is cone with vertex $a$ and base $B$ if each point not equal to $a$ is expressed uniquely as $\lambda a+\mu b$ where $b\in B$, $\lambda,\mu\geq 0$, $\lambda+\mu=1$.
>
> A subset $P\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a polyhedron if each point $a\in P$ has a cone neighbourhood $N=aL$ in $P$, where $L$ is compact. Note that the case $L=\emptyset$ is not excluded so that a point is a polyhedron.

By playing with some examples I've come to find that these subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ will look like copies of some $\mathbb{R}^{m\leq n}$ that are, as stated, translated. In such a case one could work out the above example by simply saying that subspaces are homeomorphic to some $\mathbb{R}^{m}$.

Is my interpretation accurate? Also, what would be a good reference for reading about spaces that are linear ``in the affine sense"? Thanks.

Comment: what actually is their definition of "polyhedron"?

Comment: I will add the definitions to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this post is old but I'm also struggling with their definition on polyhedra, so I know what you were going through and perhaps you can help me with my struggles with it. But yes you are thinking about it accurately. For if $L$ is an affine linear subspace of dimension $n$, it has an affine basis $\{x_0,x_1,...,x_n\}$ of $n+1$ points and therefore you can built an affine homeomorphism $L \to \Bbb R^n$ by sending $x_0$ to the origin and the rest $x_i$ to the standard linear basis of $\Bbb R^n$. So you can translate the problem to $\Bbb R^n$ and find a cube $ε$-neighborhoud. Moving back to $L$ you will have your cone neighborhoud.

Bloch's A First Course in Geometric Topology and Differential Geometry has a nice appendix section about affine linear algebra.

Comment: Thank you. I have learned quite a bit about affine geometry since I made the original post, but your answer is clarifying.

Comment: You 're welcome. Have you had any luck with Rourke and Sanderson? Because I would be grateful for any help in a recent question I posted. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3568274/about-cell-complexes-in-rourke-and-sanderson